# Limit drag movements to a circular SVG boundary

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, drag

[Here is a sample of the D3.js visualization](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/PcjUR/71/) that I am working on right now:

[image]

Here, the grey circle is the SVG container. I would like to limit the drag of the green bubbles to the grey circle boundary.

I found [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1557377) and I used it in my code, but I got two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined // points to d3.v3.min.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined  // points to line X marked in the code below
```

It seems I cannot use `.call(drag)` with Force Layout.

How do I get this working? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/PcjUR/72/)

JS:

```
var data = {
    name: "layout",
    children: [
        {name: "AxisLayout", size: 6725},
        {name: "BundledEdgeRouter", size: 3727},
        {name: "CircleLayout", size: 9317},
        {name: "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
        {name: "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
        {name: "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
        {name: "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
        {name: "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
        {name: "Layout", "size": 7881},
        {name: "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
        {name: "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
        {name: "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
        {name: "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
        {name: "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
        {name: "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
    ]
};

var margin = {
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
},
width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var n = data.children.length,
    m = 1,
    padding = 6,
    radius = d3.scale.sqrt().range([0, 12]),
    color = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(m)),
    x = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(m)).rangePoints([0, width], 1);

var nodes = d3.range(n).map(function () {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m), //color
        v = (i + 1) / m * -Math.log(Math.random()); //value
    return {
        radius: radius(v),
        color: color(i),
        cx: x(i),
        cy: height / 2,
    };

});

nodes.forEach(function(item, index){
    item.radius = 20;
});

//console.dir(nodes);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height])
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(0)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) {
    return d.radius;
    })
    .style("fill", function (d,i) {
        return "green";
    })
    .call(force.drag)
    .call(drag);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("drag", dragmove);

function tick(e) {
    circle.each(gravity(.2 * e.alpha))    // line X
        .each(collide(.5))
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.x;
    })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.y;
    });
}

// Move nodes toward cluster focus.
function gravity(alpha) {
    return function (d) {
        d.y += (d.cy - d.y) * alpha;
        d.x += (d.cx - d.x) * alpha;
    };
}

// Resolve collisions between nodes.
function collide(alpha) {
    var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
    return function (d) {
        var r = d.radius + radius.domain()[1] + padding,
            nx1 = d.x - r,
            nx2 = d.x + r,
            ny1 = d.y - r,
            ny2 = d.y + r;
        quadtree.visit(function (quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
                    y = d.y - quad.point.y,
                    l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                    r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;
                if (l < r) {
                    l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
                    d.x -= x *= l;
                    d.y -= y *= l;
                    quad.point.x += x;
                    quad.point.y += y;
                }
            }
            return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
        });
    };
}

function dragmove(){
    console.log("dragging..");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, after a lengthy discussion in the comments, I came up with this final solution:

```
var pointerEl = document.getElementById("pointer");
var canvasEl = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas = {
    width: canvasEl.offsetWidth,
    height: canvasEl.offsetHeight,
    top: canvasEl.offsetTop,
    left: canvasEl.offsetLeft
};
canvas.center = [canvas.left + canvas.width / 2, canvas.top + canvas.height / 2];
canvas.radius = canvas.width / 2;


window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var result = limit(e.x, e.y);
        pointer.style.left = result.x + "px";
        pointer.style.top = result.y + "px";
}

function limit(x, y) {
    var dist = distance([x, y], canvas.center);
    if (dist <= canvas.radius) {
        return {x: x, y: y};
    } 
    else {
        x = x - canvas.center[0];
        y = y - canvas.center[1];
        var radians = Math.atan2(y, x)
           return {
               x: Math.cos(radians) * canvas.radius + canvas.center[0],
               y: Math.sin(radians) * canvas.radius + canvas.center[1]
           }
        } 
    }

function distance(dot1, dot2) {
    var x1 = dot1[0],
        y1 = dot1[1],
        x2 = dot2[0],
        y2 = dot2[1];
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0zLuatr/)

The solution uses this other [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Asn6/).

Answer (score 2):

What you can do its put a constraint to drag event:

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/5wssqqdw/1/

```
var drag = force.drag()
        .on("drag", dragmove);
```

in this example I have put in place a rectangular constraint(I leave to you the task to put in place the circle constraint :)):

```
function dragmove(d) {
      if (d.py > 300) d.py = 300;
      if (d.py < 100) d.py = 100;

      if (d.px > 300) d.px = 300;
      if (d.px < 100) d.px = 100;

    }
```

Comment: How do I put in the circle constraint? I googled but dint get any hint. Sorry, new to D3.js

Comment: @indieblue Just compute the euclidean distance between the circle centers and compare it to the radius of your constraint minus the radius of the small circle.

Comment: @Baz I have calculated the Euclidian distance, line # 70 in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/5wssqqdw/3/). The radius of constraint minus the radius of the small circle is `180`. I didnt get how you mean to compare this. Also, what do I set the `px` and `py` of the smaller circle to?

Comment: Setting `px` and `py` is straight forward if the constraint is a square, but in my case its a circle. I believe `px` and `py` will be different for every point at the boundary of the outer circle. I am confused how to restrict the drag out of these points.

Comment: @indieblue px and py are the center of smal circle, so it is the point which you have to compare to boundary of you rounded svg, what I have solved for you is the mechanism to apply a constrain to your drag event

Comment: @wintermute To compare px and py of small circle, I would need the x and y coordinates of a point at the boundary. Which point would that be?

Comment: I would like to know how do I choose that point and how to get co-ordinates of that point.

Comment: @indieblue You can probably use some code from [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Asn6/). It's not d3, but the math should be the same.

Comment: @Baz That fiddle was very helpful! [Here is my progress so far](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/5wssqqdw/5/). One small thing remaining is that I do not want the bubbles to go out of the outer circle. As of now, if you drag them out, you can see that half of the bubble is out of the circle. To restrict this, I changed the values (+200) at line # 77 and 78 to 180 and then to 220, but it didnt help. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Baz you should put a complete answer to this question

Comment: @indieblue Ok, I found a final solution, please see my answer.

Comment: @wintermute Fair enough, posted an answer.

Comment: @InferOn - if you cant answer the question, don't reply

Comment: @hakan-bilgin are you ok?

Comment: The question is to limit movement with a circular boundary. Your reply is rectangular and is incorrect. No need for you to reply